# VS2010 Ultimate Profiler failing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, profiling

I'm trying to profile (via the Instrumentation setting) a large and complicated program, but the profiler kept failing. I tried again with a tiny main-only program and got the same error `File contains no data buffers`. What's going on?

The full templatized and sanitized output follows:

```
Setting linker /PROFILE switch (required for instrumentation) on project [Filename and Path to .vcxproj].
Project will be rebuilt.
Profiling started.
Instrumenting [Filename and path to .exe] in place
Info VSP3049: Small functions will be excluded from instrumentation.
Microsoft (R) VSInstr Post-Link Instrumentation 10.0.40219 x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
Warning VSP2005: Internal instrumentation warning: The object '\Users\[UserFolder]\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk9E8B.tmp' must be rebuilt with approved tools.
File to Process:
   [Filename and path to .exe] --> [Filename and path to .exe]
Original file backed up to [Filename and path to .exe].orig
Warning VSP2005: Internal instrumentation warning: The object '\Users\[UserFolder]\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk9E8B.tmp' must be rebuilt with approved tools.
Successfully instrumented file [Filename and path to .exe].
Data written to [Project Path]\[Project Name]130824.vsp.
Profiling finished.
File contains no data buffers
File contains no data buffers
Analysis failed
Profiling complete.
```